# Ubuntu 14.10 won't display

Tags: 14.04, 14.10

I had Ubuntu 14.04 for a few weeks, then today when I turned on my PC it prompted me to update to 14.10. After downloading and installing everything, it told me to restart my computer. It turned off and turned back off, but the screen never displayed anything. The computer is on but it won't display, it just says "no signal". What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the greeter and it worked. I think it was a problem with the X.Org drivers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace vga card

Check data cable

If you got a signal from your screen, boot in rescue mode and check your system.

Comment: I'm using HDMI to connect the PC to my Samsung TV, and while it's booting the Asus screen comes up and so does the purple Ubuntu screen for a bit then it just stops and no signal.